# Vertical align image in unordered list in Opera and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, opera

In the example of the following code,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.gallery li {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="gallery">
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/000000.png" />
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I found that, only Firefox can make it vertically center. While Opera and Chromium (Google Chrome) cannot do so. Is there anyway to solve this in Opera and Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `DOCTYPE` before the `html` element, e.g.,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```